# SnapshotParser using FirestorePagingAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I tried to have in my model the `id` of the document but when I access it the value of the id is `null`.

In fragment/activity:

```
public class MyEventsFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private FirestorePagingAdapter mAdapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirebaseFirestore;

    public MyEventsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MyEventsFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyEventsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mFirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Query query = mFirebaseFirestore.collection("events");

        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(10)
                .setPageSize(20)
                .build();

        FirestorePagingOptions<Event> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Event>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, config, new SnapshotParser<Event>() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Event parseSnapshot(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                        Event evt = new Event(
                                snapshot.getId(),
                                snapshot.getString("titre"),
                                snapshot.getString("sport"),
                                snapshot.getString("lieu"),
                                snapshot.get("date", Timestamp.class),
                                snapshot.get("dateLimit", Timestamp.class));
                        Log.i("TEST", evt.toString());
                        return evt;
                    }
                })
                .build();

        mAdapter = new EventFirestorePagingAdapter(options, getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_events, container, false);

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewListEvent);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

EventFirestorePagingAdapter (extends FirestorePagingAdapter):

```
 public class EventFirestorePagingAdapter extends FirestorePagingAdapter<Event, EventFirestorePagingAdapter.EventViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;

    public EventFirestorePagingAdapter(@NonNull FirestorePagingOptions<Event> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView titre, sport, lieu, date;

        public EventViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titreRecyclerView);
            sport = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sportRecyclerView);
            lieu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lieuRecyclerView);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateRecyclerView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*for(Map.Entry<String, Object> map: getItem(getAdapterPosition()).getData().entrySet()){
                Log.i("TEST", map.getKey());
            }*/

            Event event = getItem(getAdapterPosition()).toObject(Event.class);
            Log.i("TEST", "id = " + event.getId());
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "OnClick on position : " + getAdapterPosition() + " \nTest : " + event.getTitre() + "\nId : " + event.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Event model) {
        holder.titre.setText(model.getTitre());
        holder.sport.setText(model.getSport());
        holder.lieu.setText(model.getLieu());
        holder.date.setText(model.getDate().toDate().toString());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)     {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new EventViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

Event class :

```
public class Event {
    private String id;
    private String titre;
    private String sport;
    private String lieu;
    private Timestamp date;
    private Timestamp dateLimit;

    public Event(){ } // Needed for Firebase

    public Event(String id, String titre, String sport, String lieu, Timestamp date, Timestamp dateLimit) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titre = titre;
        this.sport = sport;
        this.lieu = lieu;
        this.date = date;
        this.dateLimit = dateLimit;
    }

    // ... getters & setters
}
```

Debug :

1) TEST: Event{id='c5jUGQc4c7SHzbpT6N01', titre='Final PSG/MARSEILLE', sport='Football', lieu='Bercy', date=Timestamp(seconds=1550844000, nanoseconds=0), dateLimit=Timestamp(seconds=1551009600, nanoseconds=0)}

2) TEST: id = null

Firestore database:

[Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQgFO.png)

[Gist with the same issue](https://gist.github.com/Tilkeii/6995db9c090ba8a3f70f699ab78daecf)

Answer :

SnapshotParser did not work as i expected but i find out how to access to the id of the document in the onClick(). I replaced [this line](https://gist.github.com/Tilkeii/6995db9c090ba8a3f70f699ab78daecf#file-customadapter-java-L49) by this following code :

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = getCurrentList().get(getAdapterPosition());
Chat chat = documentSnapshot.toObject(Chat.class);
chat.setId(documentSnapshot.getId());
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the id, inside your adapter class? Please show us more code.

Comment: @AlexMamo That's right, i'm trying to get the id inside my custom adapter class. I've edited my post to add more code

Comment: The id of the document exists in the database? Please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo The id of the document is the default id from firestore database. I added a picture of my db

Comment: And you want to get that `c5jUGQc4c7SHzbpT6N01`, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, but i need to retrieve it later when i click on an item from my recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> yes, but i need to retrieve it later when i click on an item from my recyclerview

Because you are using a `FirestorePagingAdapter` and you aren't able to use something like this:

```
String id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId(); //Works only with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
```

You need to store the id of the document as property of your document. As I see in your `Event` class, the property `id` exists but in the database there is no `id` property that holds the document id. To solve this, you need to pass the id of the document to the `Event` constructor when you are creating a new object like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference eventsRef = rootRef.collection("events");
String id = eventsRef.document().getId();
Event event = new Event(id, titre, sport, lieu, date, dateLimit);
eventsRef.document(id).set(event);
```

Comment: i think i will reconsider my schema for my database. First time using Firestore and using subcollection seems pretty bad. I will try something new

Comment: @Alexsamo Even if i change my database, the problem will persist. I made a gist about this problem https://gist.github.com/Tilkeii/6995db9c090ba8a3f70f699ab78daecf. I maybe will doing something custom without using FirebaseUI

Comment: As long as you are using the same database, in which your items do not contain the id, the problem will persist. So you should remove that data, add fresh one according to my answer and use the id where is needed. Does it work this way?

Comment: I just find out how to do it, thanks for your help ! How should i put the answer ?

Comment: What did you find?

Comment: I edited my initial post. I did that in the beginning but it didn't worked i don't remember why. That's why i struggled in this issue

Comment: But I don't understand. You said you have a problem with the `Event` class and the solution is to set the id to the `Chat` class?

Comment: Event class is from my real project. Chat class is for the minimal example to produce the issue in the gist a gave.